# Multixterm - "can't find package Expect"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcl, expect, xterm

I am attempting to open multixterm on my desktop machine, but I end up with the error:

`usr:~> multixterm 
can't find package Expect
    while executing 
"package require Expect"
    (file "/usr/local/bin/multixterm" line 6")`

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried running multixterm on my laptop and on a friend's machine, and there is no issue there. Both Expect and multixterm exist in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

Update: I've also found that neither kibitz nor autoexpect will run. I now assume that there is an issue with where the programs are looking for Expect. Does anyone know how I can verify/check that?

Comment: @nwk Hello. My OS is Linux 3.13.0-24-generic Ubuntu.

Comment: Why is Expect installed in `/usr/local/bin`? Did you not install it with `apt`?

Comment: I am not sure. I confess that this is an older work machine, and past users took care of installing everything. It is primarily used as data acquisition for experiments, and does not have an internet connection.

Comment: Try `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin multixterm`.

Comment: I tried that and received a `Bad : modifier is in $ (/).` error. I escaped the colon with    `PATH=$PATH\:/usr/local/bin multixterm` and received a `Command not found.` error.

Comment: I would also like to add that I received a long, convoluted path name before the `Command not found.` error. I apologize for not mentioning that sooner.

Comment: Check the [requirements for multixterm](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html#sect15) -- have you satisfied them?

Comment: @glennjackman I have. I tried the fix by whjm below, and that worked. I assume there was just an issue with where the programs were looking for the `Expect` package.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, run `ldd /usr/local/bin/expect` to find out where the *Expect* library (`libexpect`) is. For example:

```
% ldd /usr/bin/expect | grep libexpect
    libexpect.so.5.45 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpect.so.5.45 (0x00007f230f348000)
%
```

Then, export the [`TCLLIBPATH`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1787) var with the `libexpect` directory. For example (seems like you're using [csh](/questions/tagged/csh)):

```
% setenv TCLLIBPATH /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Then run your `multixterm` command.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I'll have to remember this for similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you! The site is telling me that my reputation is currently not high enough to influence the public vote. I did try to vote your answer up. :(

Comment: `export TCLLIBPATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"` has no effect on this in Ubuntu 18.04 with bash 4.4.19 and expect 5.45.4. Bummer.

Comment: @rjurney: On Ubuntu 16.04 I needed to set path to: ```export TCLLIBPATH=/usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu```. Exactly in that directory is installed package Expect.

Comment: For linuxbrew: `export TCLLIBPATH="$TCLLIBPATH /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib"`

Answer (score 2):

Expect was dropped from ubuntu's default installation,

run once:

```
conda install -c eumetsat Expect
```

and things should work again.

Comment: This only works on Linux unfortunately. The package doesn't exist for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience on Ubuntu, `libexpect.so` obtained through `apt` cannot be used for `package require` because the file contains 3 `undefined-symbol`s. (E.g. [Debian Bug report logs - #890228](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890228))

So I compiled the `libexpect.so` from its source. To do so, I had to compile 3 sources: [Tcl, Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html), and [Expect](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index).

After decompressing sources, installing by following:

```
$ cd /path/to/install
$ mkdir tcl tk expect
$
$ /path/to/download/tcl8.*.*/unix/configure \
      --prefix=/path/to/install/tcl
$ make ; make install
$
$ /path/to/download/tk8.*.*/unix/configure \
      --with-tcl=/path/to/install/tcl \
      --prefix=/path/to/install/tk
$ make ; make install
$
$ /path/to/download/expect5.*.*/configure \
      --with-tclconfig=/path/to/install/tcl/lib \
      --with-tkconfig=/path/to/install/tk/lib \
      --prefix=/path/to/install/expect
$ make ; make install
```

gave me the file `/path/to/install/expect/libexpect5.*.*.so` for 64-bit architecture without `undefined-symbol`s.

Here are 2 useful links about compiling:

- [How to Compile Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html)
- [[SOLVED] configuration error: Can't find Tcl configuration definition](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/configuration-error-can%27t-find-tcl-configuration-definition-4175434069/)

Finally, in the case `TCLLIBPATH` does not work, [`unwarp`ing approach](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Expect+and+Tclkit) using [TclKits](https://tclkits.rkeene.org/fossil/wiki/Downloads) with [sdx](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tclkit/downloads) can be remedy. On Ubuntu, I used one for RHEL5 x86_64.